# Python Script for Collecting Data from Outlook

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Hno.png)Could anyone help me in getting the proper python script for extracting specific data from a mail body from specific user. The data may be email id, Name, Mobile no and so on.
Scenario  : I am getting mail from a specific person(in my scenario i will be getting from multiple persons. If i get to know on how to do this for 1 person then I can use it for multiple persons) who is sending the details like Email-id, Mobile no and Name. I want to extract this data to specific excel. I have tried a lot but I am not getting how to extract.

Comment: Please share what have you tried till now with code.

Comment: post your sample code

Comment: #import the win32com library
import win32com.client

# get Outlook application object
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

# get the Namespace / Session object
namespace = Outlook.Session

# get Inbox Folders' name
inboxfolder = namespace.Folders.Folders('Inbox')

# get messages on Inbox folder
messages = inboxfolder.Items

# get message contents
for message in messages:
    sender = message.Sender
    receiver = message.To
    cc = message.Cc
    subject = message.Subject
    body = message.Body

Comment: Amresh above is the code. I tried to put it in order. but I am not getting that how to put. I am new to Stackoverflow. If you know how to share the code in better way please let me know

Comment: There's an option to insert code in your question. Look at the markdown editor on top.

Comment: Amresh I have attached the screenshot for the same.